# iOS buttons become unclickable after making a floating layout

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

I'm creating a custom action bar and my idea is that the actionbar must be transparent (thats why I can't/don't want to use the native one) and behind the action bar there must be content (an image in this case).

I tried multiple ways and all of them with the same result, the iOS button become unclickable for no reason.

Ok, so I have an `AbsoluteLayout` inside I have `GridLayout` fixed on top as the custom actionbar and then a `ScrollView` with 100% width and height, inside the scrollview there's some content. The problem is as soon as I put a button inside the `GridLayout` this become unclickable only on iOS because in Android works just fine.

Let me show you my example with some code:

```
<Page actionBarHidden="true">
        <AbsoluteLayout>
            <GridLayout rows="50, *" backgroundColor="red" top="0" left="0" height="50" id="bar">
                <Button text="click" @tap="goToDetailPage" id="buttondelsous"></Button>
            </GridLayout>
            <ScrollView backgroundColor="blue" width="100%" height="100%" top="0" id="content">
                <WrapLayout>
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Label text="this is behind"></Label>
                    </StackLayout>
                </WrapLayout>
            </ScrollView>
        </AbsoluteLayout>
    </Page>
```

As for the styles forcing the custom actionbar being in front of the scrollview I have:

```
#bar {
        z-index: 5;
        width: 100%;
    }

    #content {
        z-index: 2;
    }
```

This looks like this on Android:

[image: Android example]

Same way on iOS but the button "Click" is not working, like if it was behind something..

Any idea on how to fix this or any other approach to get what I need? Remember behind the action I must be able to place content (like a background image that I don't want to place in the `Page` tag itself but in another layout)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A wise man once told me that Nativescript stacks elements in the order you list them. Try flipping around the order so the button is listed last in the template. I believe you won't even need the z-index line if you flip the order around.

should look like

```
<Page actionBarHidden="true">
  <AbsoluteLayout>
    <ScrollView backgroundColor="blue" width="100%" height="100%" top="0" id="content">
      <WrapLayout>
        <StackLayout>
          <Label text="this is behind"></Label>
        </StackLayout>
      </WrapLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <!-- I'm listed second so I will be on top even though I have row="0" -->
    <GridLayout rows="50, *" backgroundColor="red" top="0" left="0" height="50" id="bar">
      <Button text="click" @tap="goToDetailPage" id="buttondelsous"/>
    </GridLayout>
  </AbsoluteLayout>
</Page>
```

Comment: Adding to @ShawnPacarar's answer, Yet not sure about your final goal but looking at your screenshot you don't need so much layouts / ui elements to achieve that, just a Grid with a Button and StackLayout could have done the job. You might want to checkout https://www.nslayouts.com/ if you are not familiar with the layouts.

Comment: @Shawn Pacarar Wow, simple as that? Been going crazy about this for a few days. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Manoj I'll definetely check the website and read more about layouts. Thanks for the tip!